# Значение одинарных кавычек перед и после процента в операторе like

Tags: веб-программирование, php, запрос, sql, mysql

Зачем нужны одинарные кавычки перед и после процента в операторе like в запросе:

```
$query="select * from books where ".$_POST['searchtype']." like '%" .$_POST['searchterm']. "%'";
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таков синтаксис SQL. LIKE позволяет проводить поиск по символьным строкам, а строковые литералы в SQL ограничиваются одинарными кавычками

Comment: А важно какие именно кавычки? ` или '?

Comment: насчет MySQL не скажу - не работал с ним, а в MS SQL нужны такие : __'__